# How to wait on a long running task that raises events without blocking?

Tags: c#, ios, events, xamarin.ios

I would like to start a task that contains code that would:

- Raises an event multiple times.
- Wait (using a CancellationToken) for it to exit.

At this moment the event handler is never called, so I assume that this is because the thread is blocked waiting on the cancellation token.

Here is the code:

```
this.scannerTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () => this.Scanner(),
    this.scannerCancellationTokenSource.Token,
    TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
    TaskScheduler.Default);

private void Scanner()
{
...
this.scanner = new CLLocationManager();
this.scanner.DidRangeBeacons += HandleDidRangeBeacons;
...
try
{
    this.scannerCancellationTokenSource.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne();
}
catch(OperationCanceledException) { }
}

public void StopScanner()
{
    this.scannerCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
}

// This is the event handler
private void HandleDidRangeBeacons(object sender, CLRegionBeaconsRangedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705810/how-to-raise-an-event-inside-a-task) but I'm not sure it applies to me.

I would say that I can't use async/await because I do not want to block the calling threads that will start and stop the scanner. Am I right?
Is there a solution to have events being fired inside my task?

Comment: you prolly need to follow `CLLocationManager` documentation ... as your code doesn't seems to sending any events per se

Comment: I have the same code working from the UI thread in a sample application, so CLLocationManager's DidRangeBeacons events are fired correctly. My problem is that I can't use the UI thread in my real application.

Comment: it has nothing to do with [C#](https://dotnetfiddle.net/39QWYm) but how `CLLocationManager`  works (seems like apple stuff) ... so please add right tags ...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're setting up the scanner correctly - at least from the limited code I can see.  Threading is probably not the issue since the events will be fired on their own thread.

There are a number of other setup steps to get `CLLocationManager` working correctly - **[especially on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation)**.  You really need to debug this on a real device with real beacons.  I used [faraday fabric](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=faraday%20fabric) to simulate the beacons entering into and exiting the range of the mobile device.  This helped a TON since you don't have to actually move the devices around the room - although it's good for your brain to get up and get away from the screen for a bit.

In response to your edit, in order to affect the UI from the thread running `DidRangeBeacons`, you have to use `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/main-thread

Comment: This is what I'm doing using the code found in the AirLocate sample ported to Xamarin.iOS. I have forked the repo to use my own proximity Uuid and it works very well. I'm successfully ranging the beacons. You can access the code [here](https://github.com/omatrot/AirLocate).

Comment: Just for confirmation: I do not need to affect the UI from the thread running DidRangeBeacons. Secondly, I have modified the Xamarin sample to run the CCLocationManager creation, handler assignment and regions monitoring in a Task, and I reproduce my problem. This means that event delegates are not called outside of the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no need to start a Task and wait on a CancellationToken.
Just run the code that starts the scanner, using NSRunLoop.Main.InvokeOnMainThread() for the creation of the CLLocationManagerObject instance.

Here is the new code.

```
private void Scanner()
{
    ...
    // We need a message loop for events to be dispatched to our delegate
    NSRunLoop.Main.InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        this.scanner = new CLLocationManager();
    });
    this.scanner.DidRangeBeacons += HandleDidRangeBeacons;
    ...
}
```

Thanks for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57361327/15186) on a similar question.